# WSO2 ESB log is too big, how to set?

Tags: logging, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I do a performance test on WSO2 ESB. And I found the log is too big that can not open. The biggest file is 7.20GB. I think this is a big problem. I want to set every log file less than 20MB, and I want delete old logs automatic. How to set this? Anyone can help me?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can configure logging in ESB_HOME/repository/conf/log4j.properties file.

Add following configurations in the `log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`section.

```
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=1000
```

So this will ensure total 2MB * 1000 will be used. i. e first 1000 entries of 2MB chunks will be retained

Comment: Thank you very much. And how to set http_access_2012-12-19.log?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure  http_access_log by editing the catalina-server.xml which is located {CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/tomcat directory and add renameOnRotate in the AccessLogValve

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs" 
renameOnRotate="true" prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log  pattern="combined" />

Please refer [1] for more details

[1] - http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/07/configure-access-logging-in-wso2.html