# how to delete logs in wso2 api manager periodically

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using a combination of WSO2 API Manager and Identity server.
Now my server machine gets full because of logs. Though logs getting rotated , they are not being deleted.
Is there a way to manage logs in WSO2?  May be automatically delete them after a time period. Or limit the size if logs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure logging in `repository/conf/log4j.properties` file.

Add following configurations in the `log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`section.

```
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=1000
```

So this will ensure total 20MB * 1000 will be used. i. e first 1000 entries of 20MB chunks will be retained

Ref: [WSO2 ESB log is too big, how to set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947211/wso2-esb-log-is-too-big-how-to-set)

Comment: Will it delete the logs after a certain period of time? ie delete the rolled log files?

Comment: log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender.
[2017-11-22 00:57:24,358]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...

what does this mean?

Comment: I think my appender is CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender.. What change do i have to do?